# rails - Creating a Secure ID / Password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for a RAIL way to create a very secure UID that will act as a authentication token.

I had been using UUID but was told they are not secure. I'd like to learn, what is the method of choice these days in ruby/rails 3?

Comment: Secure against what? Collisions? That should depend on the way you generate them and how many you are planning to use.

Comment: I plan on using a LOT, 100000s, secure against some one being able to easy guess or find an ID. think of this as a password. Suggestions?

Comment: uuid cannot be guessed, unless you wish to spend trillion years guessing..

Comment: I'd suggest using something like devise (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication.

Comment: It's not for authentication. It's something else that was just an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is in no way Rails specific.

UUID is not secure for the simple fact that it is a **unique** identifier and it contains 'constant' parts of a given machine (e.g. it might use the MAC address for a machine), which makes it easier to guess.

If you want 100k+ strings without someone guessing one, you need to be able to distribute your keys across a large key-space. Let me explain:

If you only need 1 key (let's), you might pick 'A'. In a key-space of A-Z you have 1:26 chance of guessing it. Now, if you'd extend your key-space to A-Za-z you have a 1:52 chance of guessing.

Need more security still? Use a longer key: 'AA' 1:2704 chance.

Now, if you'd want to have 2000 keys and use a key length of 2 (e.g. 'AA'), there's a `2000:2704 => 1:1.352` chance someone might guess it. Pretty bad.

So, the key here is to pick a very long key size. With `Digest::SHA1` you get 40-character keys (using Hex, with 16 different values per character). That's `1.46150164e48` unique values. Your 100k values should be random enough.

Edit:

With 40-digit HEX SHA1 values you have a `1:461501640000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` chance of guessing one. That takes ages.

Comment: Very interesting! how do you use Digest::SHA1 in rails?

Comment: To add up to this question, can this Hex SHA1 algorithm be used as Authentication tokens that i can distribute to my users who would like to connect to my app via an API? Is this what the other giants like google, twitter, facebook etc has been using to generate API keys? If yes, then how would i implement this in Rails? any specific class or library for this? Thanks!

Comment: In rails I can generate one of these keys with "Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("test")". What do you use to unencrypt?

Comment: Also, what do you use for the variable "test" commonly, given I need something random?

Comment: SHA1 keys are safe to distribute as an API key. If you use `Digest::SHA1.hexdigest('test')`, you'll end up with the same key. Normally you take some user data (id, email, etc.) + some random value (named 'salt'), concat them into a string and then SHA1 that. You can't decode the string, store it in your database. Re-encode the id, email, salt etc. again, and you can compare SHA1 values.